# meaning of this statement?

Tags: pascal, freepascal

In a Pascal program, what does statement `s1:=[0,3,7]` mean ?

Comment: Looking through the questions you've previously asked, looks like you've gotten some good answers there. Marking the answer that worked for you as "accepted" not only thanks the author for his time, but lets future visitors what best worked for you.

Comment: Go back through your questions by clicking on your name at the top of the page. Review each question with answers. If an answer helped you, vote it up -- the up-arrow above to the number next to the answer, tho' you may not have enough points to do that. What you do have enough points for is to mark one answer as accepted. The checkbox outlines next to each answer -- if an answer worked for you, then check the checkbox. One answer per question may be checked. If none of the answers worked, it's okay to leave it unchecked - don't just check the best of a bad lot.

Answer (score 4):

s1 is a [Pascal set variable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal_(programming_language)#Set_types), and it is being initialised so that the set contains the members 0, 3 and 7.

Answer (score 2):

Pascal has first-class support for [sets](http://www.hkbu.edu.hk/~bba_ism/ISM2110/pas055b.htm). s1 is presumably declared as a set, like

```
var  s1 : set of 0..10;
```

You can then write

```
if i in s1
// true when i is 0, 3 or 7
```